# MongoDB POJO in Java producing empty document and not using fields

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

I'm using MongoDB's POJO encoder, but it's not working. it's returning an empty document only containing an _id. i have enabled the Convention for annotation based POJOs, i also enabled the private field convention so that it uses reflection for private fields. I also know that it was using the getters instead of fields, since it did work before i put @BsonIgnore on my getters, but i modify data in a getter so this is not desirable for me. Here's my code for the class i want to serialize:

```
public class PermissionPlayer {
    public static final String MONGO_COLLECTION = "permission_players";

    @BsonProperty( "uuid")
    private UUID uuid;

    @BsonProperty( "groupNames")
    private List<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @BsonProperty( "permissions")
    private List<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();

    @BsonIgnore
    private List<PermissionGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    @BsonCreator
    public PermissionPlayer(@BsonProperty( "uuid") UUID uuid, @BsonProperty( "groupNames") List<String> groupNames, @BsonProperty( "permissions") List<String> perms) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.groupNames = groupNames == null ? new ArrayList<>() : groupNames;
        this.perms = perms;
        loadGroups();
    }


    @BsonIgnore
    public void loadGroups() {
        groups = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : groupNames)
            groups.add(PermissionManager.get().getGroup(s));
        groups.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
        Collections.sort(groups);
    }

    public PermissionPlayer(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @BsonIgnore
    public void removePermission(String permission) {
        perms.remove(permission);
    }

    @BsonIgnore
    public void addPermission(String permission) {
        perms.add(permission);
    }

    @BsonIgnore
    public List<String> getPermissions() {
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>(); // individually set perms
        permissions.addAll(perms);
        for (PermissionGroup g : groups) {
            permissions.addAll(g.getPermissions());
```

and here is the Mongo class for database access & how i construct the client:

```
public class Mongo {

    private static MongoClient client = null;
    private static MongoDatabase database = null;

    public static final CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            MongoClientSettings.builder().uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD).build().getCodecRegistry(),
            CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                    .conventions(Arrays.asList(Conventions.ANNOTATION_CONVENTION, Conventions.SET_PRIVATE_FIELDS_CONVENTION)).automatic(true).build())
    );


    public static void connectDatabase() {
        String db = Main.env.get("DATABASE_NAME");
        String uri = Main.env.get("DATABASE_URL");
        client = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(uri)).
                uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD).codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build());

        database = client.getDatabase(db);
    }

    public static MongoCollection<Document> getCollection(String name) {
        return database.getCollection(name.toLowerCase());
    }

    public static MongoDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the Conventions to no avail. also i have followed an article on this by MongoDB itself which you can find [here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/java/java-mapping-pojos/).